# C# String.Contains() não funciona, nem mesmo derivados de busca em string

Tags: c#, string, comparação, contains

Tenho um método em meu código que busca o nome de uma pessoa dentro de uma string porém sempre retorna false. Inclusive quando o nome existe dentro da string. O que é totalmente inexplicável.

Tentei usar o Contains ex:

```
linha.Contains(nome);
```

tentei usar a linha splitada ex:

```
linhaSplit.Any(a=>a.Equals(nome))
```

tentei inclusive o foreach pra provar que eu não estava ficando louco.

```
foreach(var item in linhaSplit){
   if(item == nome){
      return true;
   }else{
      return false;
   }
}
```

e mesmo assim, como disse anteriormente, mesmo tendo valores idênticos em ambos os lados de comparação o resultado insiste em ser false. O que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: O `nome` dentro de `linha` estão escritos iguais (letras maiúsculas e minúsculas)?

Comment: Coloque um código real que possamos testar com valores onde dá o problema. Veja como fazer um [mcve].

Comment: Tenta o método `equals` **linha.equals(nome)** pra ver o que te retorna

Comment: Sim, eu publiquei a solução. O problema um pouco mais complexo. Já atuo a um tempo com desenvolvimento mas vira e mexe acabamos sendo pegos por alguma pegadinha do mundo de desenvolvimento. Caso achem interessante deem uma lida na minha resposta e obrigado pela Ajuda!

Answer (score 5):

O Meu problema por mais simples que possa parecer me tomou um tempo que espero poupar a vocês com esta resposta.

O grande mistério acerca destas comparações e procura de string dentro de outra string ou como queiram chamar, se deu por conta de um carácter conhecido como Cruz Lorena ou Cruz de Lorena [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]. Carácter este "invisível" aos olhos quando contida em uma string dentro do Visual Studio.

Primeiro descobri que havia algo de errado comparando o tamanho entre as strings que "eram idênticas" visualmente falando, porém distintas em seu tamanho. Para isso só precisei verificar a propriedade **Lenght** de cada uma das strings.

A partir dai, copiei ambas as strings e colei em um [criptografador MD5 online](http://www.md5.cz/)  para ver se de fato o resultado da criptografia seria diferente e por sorte ao colar no campo de texto a ser criptografado, o carácter "invisível" apareceu.

Mesmo depois de ter descoberto o carácter a unica coisa que não consegui entender ainda é o motivo, pelo qual o **Contains** não funcionou já que este carácter se encontrava ao lado do nome, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
var texto = "qualquer coisa relacionado à Gustavo"; //esse carácter é invisível aqui também.

texto.Contains("Gustavo"); //Sempre retornava false
```

Então, logo após descobrir a existência deste carácter, tentei o óbvio, o **.Replace()**! Pois, ao colar ele dentro do lugar que indica o char que deve ser substituído no VS ficou algo como:

```
texto.Replace("",""); //pois é ele ainda era invisível aqui também.
```

E claro que o VS ia reclamar.

Então pensei, porque não só recuperar os caracteres alfanuméricos que é o que preciso neste caso (eliminar os caracteres diferentes disso), então apliquei o seguinte Regex na minha string.

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]");
texto = rgx.Replace(texto, "");
```

e fez com que o  sumisse da equação!

Não sei quais as possibilidades disso acontecer com vocês também, é óbvio que dei um exemplo mais simples do que realmente aconteceu comigo, porém esse texto vem através de uma api consumida por mim, e é algo totalmente inesperado por qualquer aplicação que nunca tenha passado por isso acredito eu. Até pelo fato de não ter encontrado nenhum post ou blog falando sobre este caso em especifico e as pesquisas do google não retornarem nenhum conteúdo que ajudasse na solução do meu problema. E por este motivo decidi dividir essa experiencia com vocês, espero que ajude!